# Noticed something about audits

Tags: bug, review-audits

I noticed something about review audits:

When it's going to give me an audit, the page says, "Loading next item" for a long time (>4 seconds).

[image]

Otherwise, the wait time is <1 second.

**UPDATE: This was not a temporary bug. It is still occurring. Makes defeating audits easy.**

Confirmed by [@Videonauth](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/522934/videonauth)(1) & [@Wilf](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/178596/wilf)(2):

> 1. No nothing new, I usually know as well by this that an audit is
>      coming. Noticed that long time ago
> 2. I've noticed it occasionally previously

Comment: Is this new? People have been having trouble with the site recently.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - What kind of trouble?

Comment: No nothing new, I usually know as well by this that an audit is coming. Noticed that long time ago.

Comment: @Videonauth hax0r.

Comment: @AndroidDev long load times and message fails in chat.

Comment: @Zacharee1 No only spoiled by a fast Internet connection, when a site suddenly need a long time to load in the audits its a sign the routine is looking for a randomized deleted message to show you or a randomized up voted good one.

Comment: @Videonauth - Interesting that you noticed this as well.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - Maybe SO's server's are getting DDOSed.

Comment: Something tells me they have good protection against that.

Comment: I've noticed it occasionally previously - makes it much easier to guess if it is a review audit or not @AndroidDev no need for DDOS, sites like SO get 8 million visits a day... anyway may be worth reporting as a bug, but they will be some delay for random requests